# Resuming enumitem inside vbox

Tags: pdftex, enumerate, enumitem

I am using the following code. Is there any way to have `enumitem` resuming inside `vbox`?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of this code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a series, see the documentation

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[series=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ulrike! Your solution is quite useful!