# enumitem not resuming within itemize

Tags: enumitem, resume

I use the enumitem package to define a new enumerate environment. I want an environment with a counter that resumes. This doesn't seem to work properly if the environment is itself within an itemize environment. The following example gives 1, 2, 2, when what I want to see is 1, 2, 3. I have experimented with the use of [resume*], which can locally generate the result that I want, but I can't see any logic in how to use it. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{enumerateSpecial}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateSpecial]{resume,label=\arabic*}

% ================= %

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateSpecial}
    \item xxx
\end{enumerateSpecial}

\begin{itemize}
    \item aaa
          \begin{enumerateSpecial}
            \item xxx
            \end{enumerateSpecial}
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerateSpecial}
    \item xxx
\end{enumerateSpecial}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you need a series, see the documentation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651494/2388

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{enumerateSpecial}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateSpecial]{resume,label=\arabic*}

% ================= %

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerateSpecial}
        \item xxx
    \end{enumerateSpecial}
    \restartlist{enumerateSpecial}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item aaa
        \begin{enumerateSpecial}
            \item xxx
            \item yyy
        \end{enumerateSpecial}
        \item bbb
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{enumerateSpecial}
        \item xxx
        \item yyy
    \end{enumerateSpecial}
    
    
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Following the Ulrike Fisher comment, perhaps the best answer for You is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}



% ================= %

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[series=A]
        \item xxx
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item aaa
        \begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
            \item xxx
            \item yyy
        \end{enumerate}
        \item bbb
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
        \item xxx
        \item yyy
    \end{enumerate}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You have read my answer?